# Absorbing State vs Closed Communicating Class

Tags: probability-theory, terminology, markov-chains

According to Wikipedia,
A set of states C is a communicating class if every pair of states in C communicates with each other.
A communicating class is closed if the probability of leaving the class is zero.

**Would you call an absorbing state a closed communicating class since it cannot be left and it communicates with itself?**

However, one problem with calling an absorbing state a closed communicating class is that since it consists of only one state (obviously) - and this might not satisfy the definition of a **set of states**.

Comment: There are sets with one element, so I do not see this as a problem

Comment: However, the definition also requires it to be 'every pair of states'. Can a state and itself be a pair?

Comment: For that you need the definition of *communicating*.  [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Reducibility) it seems that you would need a positive integer $n_i$ such that $\Pr(X_{n_{i}}=i \mid X_0=i) = p_{ii}^{(n_{i})} > 0$, so yes a state and itself can be a pair.  But if the definition were to preclude that, and single-elements sets did not have a pair, then statements about properties of *every pair* of elements would be vacuously true for single-elements sets

Comment: "A set of states C is a communicating class if every pair of states in C communicates with each other." No. Actually, a set of states C is a communicating class if for every x and y in C, x communicates with y and vice versa. (And anyway, what would it mean that a pair communicates with another pair?) What is the text on Markov chains that you are following?

Comment: I am not following any textbooks, I only need the definition which is most accurate and succinct. This is just an assignment and I'm going slightly beyond its requirement.